# Hiding the Toast Notification when a push notification is received

Tags: c#, azure, windows-8, push-notification

I am using Windows azure push notifications. Every time a new notification is received a Toast is displayed with the information received, is there anyway I can disable this feature programmatically? The reason I want this is because I am trying to develop a FPS game and I am using the Push notifications to update locations, for obvious reasons I don't want the data received to get displayed.

Comment: It's not clear if you ever want to display the toasts.  Do you want them to show up when the app is not running?  Or are you just using them as a communication mechanism and preventing them from being displayed when your app is running?

Comment: Yes, using them as communication mechanism.

Comment: Raw notifications would be better suited for this purpose.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/JJ709907(v=win.10).aspx

Comment: Out of curiosity, are all the four types send by the cloud service on each push?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the toast notification by setting the expiration time of the ToastNotification to DateTime.Now, that way it would expire as soon as it is displayed. You can do that by using the PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs args that is passed.

```
 args.ToastNotification.ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now;
```

A better solution as provided by Gaurav is to use

```
args.Cancel=true;
```

Comment: I think you can just cancel that event (args.Cancel = true) to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is consume the PushNotificationReceived event and then handle it there. I did the same for one sample chat application I built. Look for the code for app.xaml.cs in my blog post here: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/08/30/how-i-built-an-awesome-chat-application-for-windows-8-with-windows-azure-mobile-service/.